# Evaluating skill level on a particular scale

Tags: survey, scales

I want to evaluate the skills of a trainer who has taught 4 different computer languages to a batch of 150 students. I have  prepared a questionnaire, which I will give to each of the students. But I am yet to decide the scale on which the students will be evaluating  the skill of the trainer for those 4 languages. I feel a scale of 10 is a  very comfortable and students can provide the feedback for the trainer based on this scale. But I have seen many a times people evaluating performance on a scale of 5. Even once I was evaluated on the scaler of 5.

Is there any significance of choosing a particular scale? I mean is there any thing like good scale , bad scale, best scale for a particular kind of feedback?

Appreciate your time for replying.

Comment: There is actually quite a literature on this in the psychometrics field - but it's been a while since I looked at it. If you search on psychometrics and answer choice or scales or some such, it should turn up quite a bit.

There are many ways to create these scales.